# Can I expand an absolutely positioned elements height according to its child element? If yes, then how?

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, material-ui

In the code below, when the state changes to expanded, the inner text overflows but the grid item does not expand.

```
<Grid item xs={10} container style={{position: 'absolute', left: '40px'}}>
       <MaterialTypography variant='h5custom' align='left' style={this.state.expanded ? { marginTop: '4px' } : { whiteSpace: 'nowrap', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis' }}>
           {details}
       </MaterialTypography>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You need to add `MaterialTypography` component in your example. I reproduced using `Typography` and it works fine.